# VSCode Format Inserts Spaces and Breaks Angular HTML on some files

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

For a small subset of HTML Files in my Angular/MEAN Stack app, invoking the Auto Formatter breaks the angular code in a number of very strange ways. The problems boil down into the following major issues:

1. Spaces inserted at the end of every quoted attribute

   `<div class="hello">` turns into `<div class="hello ">`
2. Spaces inserted arbitrarily into Angular specific directives

   `<div ng-click="vm.selected = null">` becomes `<div ng-click="vm.selected = n ull">`
3. Page hierarchy gets lost and there are "cliffs" in the indented code. This seems to be in some way related to `span` tags nested in `div` tags.

   ```
                   <div class="row ">
                       <div class="col col-xs-6 ">
                           <div class="row ">
                           </div>
                           <div class="row ">
                               <div class="col col-xs-6 text-left label-text ">Endorsements</div>
                               <div class="col col-xs-6 text-right " ng-if="job.endorsements.length ">
                                   <span class="endorsement-tile " ng-repeat="e in job.endorsements ">{{e}}<span ng-if="!$last ">, </span> </span>
                               </div>
                               <div class="info-text text-right col col-xs-6 " ng-if="!job.endorsements "><span>- - -</span></div>
                           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col col-xs-6 ">
           <div class="row ">
               <!-- more content below -->
   ```

This seems to reproduce "worst" in my environment. My other developers, using a shared workspace `settings.json` file, run into some of the indentation issues, but not the rogue `space` characters issues. The only setting in my user `settings.json` file is `editor.formatOnType: true`, and the problem persists if I remove it.

This only affects a subset of files in the project. All have the file type `.html`, with some being `filename.client.view.html`, with others being `filename.client.template.html`. The problem doesn't seem to be specific to either naming type

help?

Comment: two points: First, try to reinstall vscode, we use and it doesn't occur. second, do you classify that question as a angularjs question? If yes, can you create a plunker to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Investigation

per the suggestion by [Joaozito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2371073/joaozito-polo) I tried reinstalling VSCode, wiping ~/Library, and restarting. No Luck.

I then started at the top of the file and identified where the problems started ... Sure enough, I had an extra `"` in one of my tags!

#### Problem Tag:

`<a ng-click="vm.toggleFilter('today')""><span class="list-text"> Today </span></a>`

#### Fixed Tag:

`<a ng-click="vm.toggleFilter('today')"><span class="list-text"> Today </span></a>`

Looking closer, the second `"` is white, but the problem doesn't show up in any highlighting or `F8` searching - which would be nice...

Problem solved

### Additional Problems

There's an additional problem that comes up with angular and/or bootstrap code, or really whenever you have really long tags in your code. The problem comes with "non-structural" tags, such as `<span>`, `<button>`, etc, and how VS Code handles them in auto-formatting.

Added in one of the more recent versions of VSCode, you can enable which tags are ignored for formatting.

I've changed the default (found in the command palette under `> Workspace Settings`) from:

```
// List of tags, comma separated, that shouldn't be reformatted. 'null' defaults to all tags listed at https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content.
"html.format.unformatted": "a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, button, cite, code, dfn, em, i, img, input, kbd, label, map, object, q, samp, script, select, small, span, strong, sub, sup, textarea, tt, var",
```

to

```
"html.format.unformatted": "a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, cite, code, dfn, em, img, input, kbd, label, map, object, q, samp, script, select, small, strong, sub, sup, textarea, tt, var"
```

Hope that helps someone!